# Replacing a div with the content of another html-file ('common/...html) with VanillaJS instead of jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ecmascript-6

I would like to be able to write the following without having to import a jQuery Library in order to get the div replaced by content of a component written in another html-file:

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <script>
    $.get("common/navbar.html", function(data) {
      $("#navbar-placeholder").replaceWith(data);
    });
  </script>
  <div id="navbar-placeholder"></div>
 </body>
```

Would be happy for suggestions

Comment: You can use fetch - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: @GowthamRajJ would you mind trying to construct a fetch() from the example above? (Sry, I am quite new to JS)

Comment: No problem, I have added an answer. You might want to read further in the links given.

Comment: Definately I am checking out the link, but I feel stuck. Your example below will help alot to understand the whole materia. THX alot for the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it with *fetch* like suggested by *Gowtham Raj J* but it didn't work right away. But with a second *.then* chained after the first response it runs well:

```
fetch('common/navbar.html')
    .then(res => {
      return res.text();
    })
    .then(cont => {
      var navPlaceholder = document.getElementById('navbar-placeholder');
      navPlaceholder.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', cont);
    });
```

Comment: Please add some insight into what is going on with your code. Answers that have no commentary are likely to be deleted!

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below, you might have to change per your requirement.

```
fetch('common/navbar.html')
  .then(response => {
     var el = document.getElementById('navbar-placeholder');
     el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', response);
  })
```

Here `response` needs to be HTML.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: So I tried it ... it didn't work with the exact code you suggested. This worked though: (see code snippet in answer above)